# Solver settings for buck converter simulation in simulink

Tags: dc-dc-converter, buck, matlab, simulink

I am trying to simulate a buck converter in simulink to operate at a 200 kHz switching frequency.
[image]

The compensator settings that I am using are shown below - [image]

The desired input and output voltages are 10 V and 5 V respectively. The buck circuit block used is shown below -
[image]

The values of components used are -

[image]

I am getting the desired output 5 V but the output is a flat line always. It does not show any fluctuations before settling to 5 V. I believe I am committing some error in choosing the correct solver. I am using the simulink suggested ode23tb solver. Please let me know where I'm going wrong.

[image]